# Why doesn't this import work across packages in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is the project architecture:
[image]

Here is the Car class that won't compile:

```
package car;

import engine.Engine;

    public class Car {
        private Engine engine;

        /***
         * Constructor
         * @param engine The engine that the car object will have
         */
        Car(Engine engine) {
            engine = new Engine(engine);    // Use the Engine copy constructor
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Here is the Engine class in the engine package:

```
package engine;

public class Engine {
    private String name;
    private int displacement;

    public Engine(String name, int displacement) throws Exception {
        setName(name);
        setDisplacement(displacement);
    }
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getDisplacement() {return displacement;}

    private void setName(String name) throws Exception {
        if (name.trim().length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Engine name cannot be blank");
        }
    }
    private void setDisplacement(int displacement) throws Exception {
        if (displacement < 0) {
            throw new Exception("Engine displacement cannot be zero or negative");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click the first proposed quick fix: `import 'Engine' (engine)` ?

Comment: @Bentaye That's how I got the import statement you see in the code. Eclipse added it.

Comment: Do you have unsaved changes? What does the error message in the line of the `import` statement say?

Comment: @howlger It says "Unused import" Arrrgh!

Comment: Jugding from your screenshot and Eclipse's default project setup, there's nothing wrong with the code you posted. It should work. Try restarting Eclipse, or make a fresh project and copy your code into it.

Comment: Which Eclipse and which Java version?

Comment: Delete the Engine class and the engine package. Recreate the engine package, recreate the Engine class. then copy paste the code into it. For some reason, it seems like Eclipse might not see the engine package. Recreating it might make it visible to Eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project in Project --> clean

Comment: Is compiler added in build path.??

Comment: Yes the compiler is in the build path

Comment: Engine dependency is added in build path .??

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I didn't change the code, I deleted the project from the workspace, closed Eclipse, reopened Eclipse with a different workspace, and imported the same project into the workspace. Arrrgh.